# How can i take video using iphone camera

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i need to take the capture the video using camera.So please tell me how to do this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you know how to use `UIImagePickerController`

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> // add MediaPlayer.framework

- (IBAction) startCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController * startCamera;
    startCamera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    startCamera.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) 
    {           
        NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
        startCamera.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
        startCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        startCamera.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo ;
        startCamera.allowsEditing = YES ;

    } 
    else
    {
        startCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    }

        [self presentModalViewController:startCamera animated:YES]; 
        [startCamera release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) carefully. It will tell to you how to approach solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. Test this code only in device. Handle the recorded video in UIImagePickerDelegate method.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
picker.delegate = self; 
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])) 
{
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES]; 
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Put alert no camer found");
        // Put alert no camer found
}
[picker release];
```